# Read and use data from js file in C++

Tags: javascript, c++

I have a C++ game project using SDL. Besides, I have a .js file for the tiled map (I attach a pastebin link for more detailed: https://pastebin.com/GKqs3km5). How can I use this to create map in my project? I try ifstream to read this file but it seems doesn't right.

```
//from lesson 39 Lazyfoo
for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_TILES; ++i)
        {
            //Determines what kind of tile will be made
            int tileType = -1;

            //Read tile from file
            js >> tileType;

            //If the was a problem in reading the map
            if (js.fail())
            {
                //Stop loading map
                printf("Error loading map: Unexpected end of file!\n");
                tilesLoaded = false;
                break;
            }

            //If the number is a valid tile number
            if ((tileType >= 0) && (tileType < TOTAL_TILE_SPRITES))
            {
                tiles[i] = new Tile(x, y, tileType);
            }
```

Comment: `std::map mymap;` `map` created. Easy. Probably not what you want. Please expand on your problem to eliminate ambiguities. You may find making a [mre] helps.

Comment: sorry for the ambiguities, "create map" I mean a game map (using tiled), not std::map in C++

Answer (score 0):

Ditch the `.js` format. It was exported from Tiled, so open it in Tiled and re-export as JSON (or XML). Then use any JSON (or XML) parsing library.

There are probably specialized libraries for parsing the JSON/XML tiled maps, but since the format is so simple, you might as well use a generic library.